# Buscar informações na base de dados com validação dos parâmetros Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8

Analise a seguinte situação: virá no *request* a informação do pais que pode ser `{0, 1, 2}`. O método do reposiório ficará assim:
Nomenclatura do parâmetro do pais:

- 0: Trazer todos os países;
- 1: Apenas nacional (Brasil)
- 2: Apenas internacional

  ```
  public List<View> getDto(Request request) {
      Session session = getSession();
      session.beginTransaction();

      String hql = "select v from view v where 1=1 ";

      if(0 != request.getCountry()) {
          String hql += "and country = :country";
      }

      List<View> view = session.createQuery(hql, View.class).getResultList();

      if(0 != request.getCountry()) {
          session.setParameter(":country", request.getCountry());
      }
      return view;

  }
  ```

Terei que fazer isso para uns 10 campos. Teria uma forma mais viável de fazer essa validação e evitar tantos `if`?
Os outros campos/parâmetros apenas preciso realizar a validação de exite para adicionar mais condições no `AND (String hql += "and ....")` .
Há tbm um campo de data que precisarei realizar um `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Quais seriam estes outros 10 campos? Seriam de países também?

Comment: @Dherik, não. Seriam campos normais, com exceção do `between` na data_registro. Eles poderam vir null ou com a informação em `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode diminuir pela metade a quantidade de condicionais, usando a abordagem que você apresentou, usando um `Map` e aproveitando o mesmo `if` que concatena a condicional HQL na consulta.

Veja:

```
String hql = "select v from view v where 1 = 1 ";

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

if(0 != request.getCountry()) {
    map.put("country", request.getCountry());
    String hql += "and country = :country ";
}

// itera por todos os campos salvos no map e coloca na session como parâmetro
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    session.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Vou implementar sua idea. Curti ela +1.

Comment: deu boa obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar como eu utilizei o exemplo acima. Caso alguém precise:

```
session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
map.forEach(query::setParameter);
List result = query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Usuarios.class)).list();
session.close();
```

A classe `Usuarios.class` contém como atributos as colunas retornadas da consulta. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT nome, email FROM usuários where ativo = 1

public class Usuarios {
    private String nome;
    private String email;

    // Não precisa dos getters e setters neste caso
}
```